# Null Pointer Exception, por que al mandar valores a la clase padre Encriptacion, luego no los reciben las clases hijas para realizar los metodos

Tags: java, herencia

Clase **Encriptacion**

```
class Encriptacion {
protected String palabraM;
protected String frase;

public Encriptacion(){
}

public Encriptacion(String palabraM, String frase){
    this.palabraM=palabraM;
    this.frase=frase;
}

public boolean setPalabraM(String palabraM){
    if(palabraM.length()>=4 || palabraM.length()<=6){
        this.palabraM=palabraM;
        return true;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Palabra erronea");
    }
    return false;
}

public String getPalabraM(){
    return palabraM;
}

public void setFrase(String frase){
        this.frase= frase;
}

public String getFrase(){
    return frase;
}   
}
```

Clase **Encriptar**

```
class Encriptar extends Encriptacion{

private String palabraM;
private String frase;

public Encriptar(){
}

public Encriptar(String palabraM, String frase){
    super(palabraM, frase);
}

public void hacerEncriptacion(){
    int cont = 0;
    char arreglo [][]=null;
    System.out.println(frase.length());
    System.out.println(palabraM.length());

    int div=((int)(frase.length()/palabraM.length()));
    System.out.println(div);

    if(frase.length()%palabraM.length()!=0){
        div++;
    }
    System.out.println(div);

    arreglo = new char [palabraM.length()][div];


    for(int j=0;j<div; j++){
    for(int i=0; i<palabraM.length();i++){

            if(cont<frase.length()){
                arreglo[i][j]=frase.charAt(cont);
            }else{
                arreglo[i][j]='*';
            }
            cont++;
        }


    }

    for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++ ){
        for(int j=0; j<div;j++){
            System.out.print(arreglo[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }           
}
}
```

Clase **FARGPIA**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class FARGPIA{
public static void main(String args []){
    int opcion, opcion2;
    String palabraM;
    String frase;

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Encriptacion encriptacion =new Encriptacion();
    Desencriptar desc = new Desencriptar();
    Encriptar enc= new Encriptar();

    do{
    System.out.println("Ingrese la opcion deseada");
    System.out.println("1. Desencriptar");
    System.out.println("2. Encriptar");
    System.out.println("3. Salir");

    opcion = sc.nextInt();

    switch (opcion){

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Ingrese la frase");
            sc.nextLine();
            frase= sc.nextLine();
            encriptacion.setFrase(frase);

            System.out.println();

            do{
                System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra magica");
                palabraM= sc.next();
                encriptacion.setPalabraM(palabraM);

            }while(desc.setPalabraM(palabraM)!=true);
            System.out.println();


            desc.hacerDesencriptacion();

            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Ingrese la frase");
            sc.nextLine();
            frase= sc.nextLine();
            encriptacion.setFrase(frase);

            System.out.println();

            do{
                System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra magica");
                sc.nextLine();
                palabraM= sc.next();

            }while(enc.setPalabraM(palabraM)!=true);
            encriptacion.setPalabraM(palabraM);
            System.out.println();

            enc.hacerEncriptacion();

            break;

        case 3:
            break;
        }       

        System.out.println();
    }while(opcion!=3);
}
}
```

Comment: Como sería la duda que tenés?

Comment: me manda un error de Null Pointer Exception, por que al mandar valores a la clase padre Encriptacion, luego no los reciben las clases hijas para realizar los metodos

Comment: Para que te puedan dar una mano, editá la pregunta y agregá ahi lo que estás quriendo hacer y cuando te surge el problema, y si pudiste ver algo al respecto también agregalo. Un NPE es porque tenes una variable sin instanciar y estas queriendo ejecutar un método sobre la misma. Asi que también agregá el stack trace de la excepción.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptualmente la herencia no está bien aplicada. Cuando quieres usar herencia, defines unos atributos en la clase padre que heredarán los hijos, sin necesidad de volver a definirlos en los hijos. En el caso que expones, yo pondría los atributos palabraM y frase en la clase Encriptación, y luego nos los pondría en la clase hija Encriptar. Respecto al método main, yo haría una instancia de la clase hija, que por herencia va a heredar los atributos de la padre. El código que has puesto no está muy completo, porque veo que se usa una clase Desencriptar que no está implementada. Te pongo aquí debajo una aproximación que compila, ejecuta y no genera NPE. Espero que te sirva.Un saludo.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Encriptacion { protected String palabraM; protected String frase;
public Encriptacion(){
}

public Encriptacion(String palabraM, String frase){
    this.palabraM=palabraM;
    this.frase=frase;
}

public boolean setPalabraM(String palabraM){
    if(palabraM.length()>=4 || palabraM.length()<=6){
        this.palabraM=palabraM;
        return true;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Palabra erronea");
    }
    return false;
}

public String getPalabraM(){
    return palabraM;
}

public void setFrase(String frase){
        this.frase= frase;
}

public String getFrase(){
    return frase;
}   
}
class Encriptar extends Encriptacion{
//private String palabraM;
//private String frase;

public Encriptar(){
}

public Encriptar(String palabraM, String frase){
    super(palabraM, frase);
}

public void hacerEncriptacion(){
    int cont = 0;
    char arreglo [][]=null;
    System.out.println(frase.length());
    System.out.println(palabraM.length());

    int div=((int)(frase.length()/palabraM.length()));
    System.out.println(div);

    if(frase.length()%palabraM.length()!=0){
        div++;
    }
    System.out.println(div);

    arreglo = new char [palabraM.length()][div];


    for(int j=0;j<div; j++){
    for(int i=0; i<palabraM.length();i++){

            if(cont<frase.length()){
                arreglo[i][j]=frase.charAt(cont);
            }else{
                arreglo[i][j]='*';
            }
            cont++;
        }


    }

    for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length;i++ ){
        for(int j=0; j<div;j++){
            System.out.print(arreglo[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }           
}
}
class Main{ 
    public static void main(String args []){ 
        int opcion, opcion2; String palabraM; String frase;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Encriptacion enc =new Encriptar();
    //Desencriptar desc = new Desencriptar();
    Encriptar enc= new Encriptar();

    do{
    System.out.println("Ingrese la opcion deseada");
    System.out.println("1. Desencriptar");
    System.out.println("2. Encriptar");
    System.out.println("3. Salir");

    opcion = sc.nextInt();

    switch (opcion){

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Ingrese la frase");
            sc.nextLine();
            frase= sc.nextLine();
            enc.setFrase(frase);

            System.out.println();

           /* do{
                System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra magica");
                palabraM= sc.next();
                encriptacion.setPalabraM(palabraM);

            }while(desc.setPalabraM(palabraM)!=true);*/
            System.out.println();


 //           desc.hacerDesencriptacion();

            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Ingrese la frase");
            sc.nextLine();
            frase= sc.nextLine();
            enc.setFrase(frase);

            System.out.println();

            do{
                System.out.println("Ingrese la palabra magica");
                sc.nextLine();
                palabraM= sc.next();

            }while(enc.setPalabraM(palabraM)!=true);
            enc.setPalabraM(palabraM);
            System.out.println();

            enc.hacerEncriptacion();

            break;

        case 3:
            break;
        }       

        System.out.println();
    }while(opcion!=3);
}
}
```